# using java8 streams, how to map list of objects to map of lists by grouping with some attribute of object

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two classes Employee, Address.
And an employee can have multiple addresses.

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee("emp1", "emp1");
Employee emp2 = new Employee("emp2", "emp2");

Address address1 = new Address("city1");
Address address2 = new Address("city2");

List<Address> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(address1);
List<Address> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(address2);

emp1.setAddressList(list1);
emp2.setAddressList(list2);
```

Given the above inputs, how can I create Map<String, List> list of employees grouped by city using Java stream functions.

```
Given the above inputs, how can I create Map<String, List<Employee>> list of employees grouped by city using Java stream functions.
```

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: What is the error or issue you are facing while implementing the above scenario?

Comment: no, my question is slightly different. The key for grouping the employees is based on any city. they can have multiple addresses. each address with different city.

Map<String, List<Employee>> employeeMap = employees.stream().
                flatMap(employee -> employee.getAddressList().stream()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Address::getCity,
                        Collectors.mapping((e -> (Employee) e), Collectors.toList())
                ));

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8 stream**

You can achieve the given scenario by using the `stream` function `Collectors.groupingBy` as shown below:

**Logic:**

*Here,*

1. First I have created an additional list of `EmployeeCityMapping` object which Employee data corresponding to the city by iterating the `empList`.
2. I have used `Collectors.groupingBy` on the `List<EmployeeCityMapping>` and grouped the data based on the `city` and using `Collectors.mapping` collect the list of Employee corresponding to the city.

**Code:**

```
    public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        Address add1 = new Address("City1");
        Address add2 = new Address("City2");
        List<Address> addForEmp1 = Arrays.asList(add1,add2);
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("emp1",addForEmp1);

        Address add11 = new Address("City3");
        Address add21 = new Address("City4");
        List<Address> addForEmp2 = Arrays.asList(add11,add21);
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("emp2",addForEmp2);
        
        List<Employee> empList = Arrays.asList(emp1,emp2);

        List<EmployeeCityMapping> empWithCityMapping = new ArrayList<>();
        empList.forEach(x -> x.getAddress().forEach(y ->
                empWithCityMapping.add(new EmployeeCityMapping(x,y.getCityName()))));

        Map<String,List<Employee>> employeeGroupedByCity =
                empWithCityMapping.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EmployeeCityMapping::getCity,
                Collectors.mapping(EmployeeCityMapping::getEmp,Collectors.toList())));

        System.out.println(employeeGroupedByCity);
    }
}
```

**Address.java**

```
public class Address {

    private String cityName;
    //getters and setters and toString
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

    private String empName;
    private List<Address> address;

    public Employee(String empName, List<Address> address) {
        this.empName = empName;
        this.address = address;
    }
    //getters and setters and toString
}
```

**EmployeeCityMapping.java**

```
public class EmployeeCityMapping {

    private Employee emp;
    private String city;

    public EmployeeCityMapping(Employee emp, String city) {
        this.emp = emp;
        this.city = city;
    }

    //getters and setters and toString
}
```

Output:

```
{City2=[Employee{empName='emp1', address=[Address{cityName='City1'}, Address{cityName='City2'}]}], 
City1=[Employee{empName='emp1', address=[Address{cityName='City1'}, Address{cityName='City2'}]}], 
City4=[Employee{empName='emp2', address=[Address{cityName='City3'}, Address{cityName='City4'}]}], 
City3=[Employee{empName='emp2', address=[Address{cityName='City3'}, Address{cityName='City4'}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a custom collect like this

```
        Map<String, List<Employee>> addressEmployeeMap = employeeList.stream().collect(
            () -> new HashMap<>(), //supplier
            (map, e) -> {     //accumulator
        List<Address> addresses = e.getAddresses();
        addresses.stream().forEach(addressToCheck -> {
            if (map.containsKey(addressToCheck)) {
                map.get(addressToCheck).add(e);
            } else {
                map.put(addressToCheck.getAddressLine(), new ArrayList<>() {{
                    add(e);
                }});
            }
        });
    }, 
            (map1, map2) -> {  //combiner
        map1.putAll(map2);
    });

    addressEmployeeMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " :: " + e.getValue()));
```

This is giving the result as

```
City04' :: [Employee{firstName='thirdFirst', lastName='thirdLast', addresses=[Address{addressLine='City04''}]}]
City03 :: [Employee{firstName='twoFirst', lastName='twoLast', addresses=[Address{addressLine='City02'}, Address{addressLine='City03'}]}]
City01 :: [Employee{firstName='oneFirst', lastName='oneLast', addresses=[Address{addressLine='City01'}]}]
City02 :: [Employee{firstName='twoFirst', lastName='twoLast', addresses=[Address{addressLine='City02'}, Address{addressLine='City03'}]}]
```